# xcodebuild build xcode project with dependent project failed. dependent project's target not found

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

My main project named sample.xcodeproj dependends on sdklib.xcodeproj. The target of sdklib.xocdeproj is sdk.a.

when I build the sample.xcodeproj with xcodebuild command

```
  xcodebuild -project sample.xcodeproj
```

It failed.

```
  error: no such file or directory:'/Users/.../libsdklib.a
```

It seems the dependent project doesn't builded. I also didn't see the libsdklib.a in sdklib.xcodeproj's target path. But It runs well in xcode. So where is the sdk.a when I build sample.xcodeproj? and how can I use the xcodebuild command to build sample.xcodeproj with sdklib.xcodeproj?